# How to cancel a credit card you currently have debt on if the bank won't respond?

Tags: credit-card, germany, online-banking

Several months ago, I got a credit card from Santander. I've tried many times to get their app Santander Sign set up and after about two months, it finally worked. But I still can't sign in because their online banking just isn't available (everything else on my connection works fine, including online banking of other banks). Unfortunately, I made the mistake of actually using the credit card because I thought I could log in after finally getting their non-working app set up.

Always, https://meine.santander.de and https://api.santander.de are either not available to begin with or stop being available when I logged in. I've never even seen the online banking interface in several months of trying every few days. The connection just times out or they only show a pretty much blank page with just a logo and a footer.

I've sent them a request about paying my debt off (via their contact form) because I can't log in over two weeks ago but they haven't responded. Right now I'm trying again to call them but they just won't pick up the phone. I can already tell that in half an hour I'll be bugged out sufficiently by their music and will hang up but they won't have picked up by then.

I just want to pay my debt off and never have anything to do with Santander. I don't want their credit card. How do I do this?

Location: Germany

Edit: If anyone is still considering using Santander. It's 2022 now. They sent me a huge stack of paper about their new terms of service asking me to agree to them (the fuck i will). I sent them an email telling them that they actually confirmed that my account was canceled via a letter a long time ago, citing the date they dated the letter to. I sent that email over a month ago. Still no response.

Comment: Have you tried going to a local branch and speak to someone?

Comment: @Croves No, because I figured that they probably can't do anything anyway. But I can try the next few days.

Comment: In my experience, in the United States, most bank branches allow you to see your account balances and make payments. (I did once walk into a bank branch that turned out to be unable to accept cash payments for credit cards, but they directed me to another branch of the same bank which did accept those payments.)

Comment: I don't know about the actual problem of contacting them, but I can tell you that https://api.santander.de doesn't work here either (404 error), but https://meine.santander.de/ works and redirects to https://meine.santander.de/login/#/login/. I cannot proceed here, as I am not their customer, but till here, it works. It might still be a problem on your side. Did you try e. g. with a smart phone via a mobile connection?

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I have tried on my phone too. Most of the error messages the app popped out actually were that the server wasn't available and I've tried via wifi and via mobile connection of two different carriers. Funnily enough, right now api.santander.de actually is available to me.

Comment: For shit and giggles, I now actually tried to log in because meine.santander.de is available too and it doesn't time out upon login either. For the first time, I can see the online banking interface, albeit covered with a half transparent layer and a loading animation that just won't finish. I hate that bank.

Comment: And now just a minute later, meine.santander.de is down again. -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as was already suggested, you should go to a local branch.

Even if they can't direcly do anything for you, they might be able to tell you how to proceed.

If they can't and you…

> just want to pay my debt off and never have anything to do with Santander. I don't want their credit card.

you always can cancel a contract by sending a letter, maybe a registered one ("Einschreiben").

If you have a vague idea of how much your debt with them (including interest which might have accrued) is, just transfer the needed amount plus a certain safety amount (just to be sure) to the main account linked to that card (I suppose you have the IBAN of that account) and tell them

- to cancel all accounts with them
- to clear all debts with the outstanding amount of the main account
- to transfer the remaining amount to (your) account XY.

If/As you don't have the IBAN, you should either

- provide them in the cancellation letter with a SEPA mandate to withdraw the missing funds once (if you feel comfortable doing so) or
- ask them to tell you the amount you owe them and offer to transfer it ASAP.

Comment: I don't have the IBAN. I guess I'd get it after logging in. They also didn't send me an email with how much I need to pay and to what bank connection. But I'll go ask at a local branch.

Comment: @UTF-8 Ouch. For this case, I just added some alternative suggestions how to proceed. I wish you good luck with clearing up the situation!

Comment: *They also didn't send me an email with how much I need to pay* surely you've at least received a monthly statement with instructions on how to make payments?